# Using jQuery to gather all text nodes from a wrapped set, separated by spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

I'm looking for a way to gather all of the text in a jQuery wrapped set, but I need to create spaces between sibling nodes that have no text nodes between them.

For example, consider this HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List item #1.</li><li>List item #2.</li><li>List item #3.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If I simply use jQuery's `text()` method to gather the text content of the `<div>`, like such:

```
var $div = $('div'), text = $div.text().trim();

alert(text);
```

that produces the following text:

> List item #1.List item #2.List item #3.

because there is no whitespace between each `<li>` element. What I'm actually looking for is this (note the single space between each sentence):

> List item #1. List item #3. List item #3.

This suggest to me that I need to traverse the DOM nodes in the wrapped set, appending the text for each to a string, followed by a space. I tried the following code:

```
var $div = $('div'), text = '';

$div.find('*').each(function() {
  text += $(this).text().trim() + ' ';
});

alert(text);
```

but this produced the following text:

> This is list item #1.This is list item #2.This is list item #3. This is list item #1. This is list item #2. This is list item #3.

I assume this is because I'm iterating through every descendant of `<div>` and appending the text, so I'm getting the text nodes within both `<ul>` and each of its `<li>` children, leading to duplicated text.

I think I could probably find/write a plain JavaScript function to recursively walk the DOM of the wrapped set, gathering and appending text nodes - but is there a simpler way to do this using jQuery? Cross-browser consistency is very important.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

jQuery deals mostly with elements, its text-node powers are relatively weak. You can get a list of all children with `contents()`, but you'd still have to walk it checking types, so that's really no different from just using plain DOM `childNodes`. There is no method to recursively get text nodes so you would have to write something yourself, eg. something like:

```
function collectTextNodes(element, texts) {
    for (var child= element.firstChild; child!==null; child= child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType===3)
            texts.push(child);
        else if (child.nodeType===1)
            collectTextNodes(child, texts);
    }
}
function getTextWithSpaces(element) {
    var texts= [];
    collectTextNodes(element, texts);
    for (var i= texts.length; i-->0;)
        texts[i]= texts[i].data;
    return texts.join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked like a charm! Thanks so much, don't know what I'd do without you, bobince. ;-)

Comment: works beautifully on `<span class="fwn fcg"><span class="fcg"><span class="fwb"><a class="profileLink" href="">Ndumiso Mlilo</a><a href=""></a></span> added a new photo.</span></span>` ^_^

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest solution I could think of:

```
$("body").find("*").contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType!==1;});
```

Comment: very elegant solution!

Comment: fails on `<span class="fwn fcg"><span class="fcg"><span class="fwb"><a class="profileLink" href="">Ndumiso Mlilo</a><a href=""></a></span> added a new photo.</span></span>`

Comment: produces `added a new photo. Ndumiso Mlilo` instead of `Ndumiso Mlilo added a new photo.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents) method to get all nodes (including text nodes), then filter down your set to only the text nodes.

```
$("body").find("*").contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType!==1;});
```

From there you can create whatever structure you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this didn't work for me. Could you expand upon your sample code? Additionally, I think `contents()` only traverses immediate children of the wrapped set (see http://api.jquery.com/contents/), not all descendants.

Comment: @Bungle that's true, `contents()` does not collect the nodes recursively but only the immediate descendants.

Comment: fails on `<span class="fwn fcg"><span class="fcg"><span class="fwb"><a class="profileLink" href="">Ndumiso Mlilo</a><a href=""></a></span> added a new photo.</span></span>`

Comment: produces `added a new photo. Ndumiso Mlilo` instead of `Ndumiso Mlilo added a new photo.`

Answer (score 0):

I built on @bobince's terrific answer to make search tool that would search all columns of a table and filter the rows to show only those that matched (case-insensitively) all of a user's search terms (provided in any order).

Here is a screenshot example:

[image]

And here is my javascript/jQuery code:

```js
$(function orderFilter() {
  // recursively collect all text from child elements (returns void)
  function collectTextNodes(element, texts) {
    for (
      let child = element.firstChild;
      child !== null;
      child = child.nextSibling
    ) {
      if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        texts.push(child);
      } else if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        collectTextNodes(child, texts);
      }
    }
  }

  // separate all text from all children with single space
  function getAllText(element) {
    const texts = [];
    collectTextNodes(element, texts);

    for (let i = texts.length; i-- > 0; ) texts[i] = texts[i].data;

    return texts.join(' ').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
  }

  // check to see if the search value appears anywhere in child text nodes
  function textMatchesFilter(tbody, searchVal) {
    const tbodyText = getAllText(tbody).toLowerCase();
    const terms = searchVal.toLowerCase().replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').split(' ');

    return terms.every(searchTerm => tbodyText.includes(searchTerm));
  }

  // filter orders to only show those matching certain fields
  $(document).on('keyup search', 'input.js-filter-orders', evt => {
    const searchVal = $(evt.target).val();
    const $ordersTable = $('table.js-filterable-table');
    $ordersTable.find('tbody[hidden]').removeAttr('hidden');

    if (searchVal.length <= 1) return;

    // Auto-click the "Show more orders" button and reveal any collapsed rows
    $ordersTable
      .find('tfoot a.show-hide-link.collapsed, tbody.rotate-chevron.collapsed')
      .each((_idx, clickToShowMore) => {
        clickToShowMore.click();
      });

    // Set all tbodies to be hidden, then unhide those that match
    $ordersTable
      .find('tbody')
      .attr('hidden', '')
      .filter((_idx, tbody) => textMatchesFilter(tbody, searchVal))
      .removeAttr('hidden');
  });
});
```

For our purposes, it works perfectly!  Hope this helps others!