# jquery remove text from all tags after x characters

Tags: jquery, html, text, tags

I'm trying to select a div's content and remove all text after the x characters. However i need to keep the tags/rich-text intact, since i don't want to end up with non-closed tags, or even worse, tags that are split in the middle.

so i need to either just empty all text from all tags after x characters - or remove everything after x characters and then auto close all tags that might have been left open.

How would I go about doing that? Is it possible to look for tags that isnt closed, and then close it? or is it possible to simply select all text after a certain point, and just remove the strings (not the html).

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is `x` the literal character `'x'`, or a variable number of characters?

Comment: Sorry that is the variable number of characters, could be 100

Comment: Have you tried using the .textContent attribute?

Comment: No how does that work? is that jquery? cant find any documentation

Comment: i've tried with .html() which seems to result in cut tags since the text is dynamic. ive also tried with .text() but this strips all tags away. but i dont know .textContent

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult and messy dealing with text nodes but there's some useful info on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836317/using-jquery-to-gather-all-text-nodes-from-a-wrapped-set-separated-by-spaces), which lead me to perform [this test](http://jsfiddle.net/BP5E7/) with *some* success:

```
var x = 10;
$("body *").each(function(){
    $(this).contents()
        .filter(function(){ return this.nodeType ==1; })
        .text($(this).text().substring(0,x));
});
```

Comment: Yeah it feels really messy. Theres is too many issues with these selections when the content is dynamic. The logic should be this: 1. select the full content of a div 2. if there is more then x characters in the TEXT not counting markup, then add ..., and remove everything after. 3. close potentially open elements that are now lacking a closing tag.

Comment: Does the text *have* to be removed? I'm struggling to understand why you need this. Might CSS `text-overflow:ellipsis` be of use to you?

Comment: Yeah that would be the perfect solution, except that only works on single-line text. The text doesnt have to be removed - simply hidden. But if you just make the box shorter, the text will end abruptly at the end of the line still in view. This makes it impossible to know where to insert the (...). Man if only text-overflow ellipsis worked on multi-line, that would make life sweet again :)